# how to join date columns defined as string data type and are in different formats in bigquery?

Tags: sql, date, join, google-bigquery, between

I have two tables Master and Platforms. I am trying to Join the two tables based on Date columns.
But the Date column in Master table is in the format YYYY-MM-DD and the data type is String,
the Date Column in Platforms table is in the format MM/DD/YY and the data type is String.

The join condition I am trying is Master.Date BETWEEN Platforms.StartDate and Platforms.EndDate

I have tried to parse and convert the columns to date but it doesn't yield any records.

```
SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", Master.Date) BETWEEN 
SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",Platforms.StartDate) AND SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",Platforms.EndDate)
```

What should I add to compare these columns?

```
Query:

select * from Master, Platforms
where
SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", Master.Date) BETWEEN 
SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",Platforms.StartDate) AND SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",Platforms.EndDate)


Master Table Ex:

Name    Date        ID
Alex    2019-01-25  1
David   2019-02-25  2
Seth    2019-03-25  3
Peter   2019-04-25  4
Taylor  2019-05-25  5

Platform Table Ex:

Type    StartDate   EndDate
Abc     01/05/19    01/31/19
Def     02/25/19    03/31/19
Ghi     05/01/19    05/24/19
klm     05/01/19    05/25/19

Expected O/P:

Name    Date        ID  Type    StartDate   EndDate
Alex    2019-01-25  1   Abc     01/05/19    01/31/19
David   2019-02-25  2   Def     02/25/19    03/31/19
Taylor  2019-05-25  5   klm     05/01/19    05/25/19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'%y'` (lower-case):

```
where SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", Master.Date) BETWEEN 
          SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', Platforms.StartDate) AND 
          SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', Platforms.EndDate)
```

`'%Y'` in a format specification treats the year as a four-digit year.  So, "19" --> "0019".  Presumably, you want "2019", which is why `'%y'` is appropriate.